# Как использовать массив в качестве аргумента метода в Java?

Tags: java

вот мой метод:

```
  static int toDec(byte[] dgnmb) {
    //тут происходят всякие манипуляции с dgnmb
    return num09;
  }
```

вот так всё нормально работает:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    byte[] dg = {1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0};
    int num = toDec(dg);
    System.out.println(num);
  }
```

а вот так нет:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(toDec({1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0}));
  }
```

Comment: Нельзя использовать массив - литерал в качестве параметра метода. Вам необходимо написать toDec(new byte[] {...})

Comment: Спасибо огромное